# Angular; Sharing data between this components

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular and I have this problem here:
I want to pass the data that I have from this service+component to another component.

I have a service doing this:

```
getRecs() {

    let recsSub = new Subject<any>();
    let recsSubObservable = from(recsSub);

    this.socket.on('recs', (recsStatus: any) => {
        recsSub.next(recsStatus);
    });

return recsSubObservable;
}
```

Then I have this parent component

```
private misRecs = null;
snackBarShown = false;

constructor (private appSocketIoService: AppSocketIoService, private snackbar: MatSnackBar) {

 let recsObservable =  this.appSocketIoService.getRecommendations();

 recsObservable.subscribe((recsStatus: any) => {
   console.log(recsStatus);
   this.misRecs = {};

    for(let property in recsStatus.output){
      if (recsStatus.output[property]) {
        this.misRecs[property] = recsStatus.output[property];
      }
    };

    this.snackbar.openFromComponent (CustomSnackBar, { duration: 5000, });

 });
 }
```

What I need is to populate a list in another component with the values obtained from `recsStatus` but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

If the component is a child component of your component (parent) you describe in the listing you can use the `@Input()` annotation.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-comp',
    template: `
    <div>
        {{ localRecStatus | json }}
    </div>
   `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input()
    localRecStatus: [];
}
```

Now you can use the component in HTML file of your parent component like this:

```
<child-comp [localRecStatus]="recStatus"></child-comp>
```

With this, you can use recStatus in your child component. However, `recStatus` must be a public variable of the parent component. With this technique, you can pass any data to child components. There is also an `@Output()` annotation you can use in combination with an EventEmitter to send data to the parent component. If the component is not a child, probably a better way is to communicate via a Service between both components.

Comment: This is the app tree:
     |- app-component
     |- - recs-component
     |- app-service
The list to populate lives in `recs-component`, the `app-compoent`is the one who will be sending the data

Comment: So you want to populate the list to app-component? Why don't you invoke the appropriate method of the service to send data in recs-component? I think you should not place too much logic and HTML into app-component. It is better to do these things with dedicated components.